# Wordpress Error when entering Paypal email address into Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I am attempting to link a client's PayPal account to Woocommerce. In the field that says PayPal Email, I am entering the client's email address that they used to create the business account. But, I am getting a return error that states A part followed by '@' should not contain the symbol ". There are no " symbols in the email address. The email address looks like this abcdefg.xyz@gmail.com. I am wondering if the . between the words before the @ symbol is the culprit for returning this error? There is only one email address in the field so it's not a problem of separating email address with the , symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the problem, you could have them add and confirm `abcdefgxyz` @gmail.com in https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email and see if that helps (Gmail ignores dots)

It would be best to configure the most recent WooCommerce module for PayPal that uses an API to process payments -- and also has Smart Payment Buttons as an available option.